# Get the total number of bytes loaded to the BufferReader before finish reading from it

Tags: java

I'm reading a large xml file using HttpURLConnection in java as follows.

```
StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder(1024);
char[] buffer = new char[4096];

BufferedReader  br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(((InputStream)new DataInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(connection.getInputStream()))),"UTF-8"));

int n = 0;
while(n>=0){
    n=br.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);
    if(n>0) responseBuilder.append(buffer,0,n);

}
```

Is there any way to get the total number of bytes loaded to the BufferedReader before finish reading it char by char / line by line / char block by char block.

Comment: If you explain what it is you want to do based on that information, then maybe someone could suggest the best way to go about it.

Comment: Thanx Dave. I need it to implement several functionality like 1. Generating a progress bar which indicate the percentage of the built file against the loaded data to the buffer, 2. Check whether the complete loaded file was built and how much percentage lost due to an exception occurred like "Out of Memory" (since this is a large file) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to find out the size of the `BufferedReader` without consuming it.

You could try using the `HttpURLConnection`'s [`getContentLength()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29) method. This may or may not work. What it certainly wouldn't do is give you the *uncompressed* size of the stream. If it's the latter that you're after, you're almost certainly out of luck.

If I have misunderstood your question, please clarify what it is exactly that you're after.

Comment: Thanx aix. But when I tried with getContentLength(), it returned me -1 that means the content length is not known.

Answer (score 0):

If the content-length header has been set then you can access that through the connection.  But if the content has been compressed then it might not be set, or might give the compressed size, where I assume you are looking for the uncompressed size.

Comment: Thanx Dave.Yep. I'm after the uncompressed size.